# Passing JavaScript data value between 2 HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to pass a value from one HTML document to the other, and this works, but when it's printing out the value, it's adding the name tag `text=` in front of it. Is there a way to get rid of the `text=` and just showing the entered value?

here is the form of the first page: `pageOne.html`

```
<form action="pageTwo.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and here the script of the second page: `pageTwo.html`

```
<script>
    var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    queryString = queryString.substring(1);
    var queries = queryString.split("&");
    document.write(queries[0]);    
</script>
```

Comment: Split `queries[0]` on the `=` character, then print the value at index `1` of the resulting array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

`GET /pageTwo.html?text=hello`

```html
<script>
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  var textValue = urlParams.get('text')
  console.log(textValue)
</script>
```

Result: `hello`